# Does anyone have details on saveEnabled for ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

So we have a ViewPager in our App that loads hundreds of fragments and we are getting a crash with TransactionTooLargeException.

So here is our setup:

1. **Activity**: We have the an activity that has the ViewPager2 and the ViewPager2 has a FragmentStateAdapter that will setup the fragments and will setup arguments/bundles for the fragments.

   The Activity has its own ViewModel and has a SavedStateHandle
2. **Fragments**: The fragments created in the ViewPager2 have their own SavedStateHandle and ViewModel.

Will setting saveEnabled to false in our viewPager2 cause any issues with any of SavedStateHandles in our activity/fragments or is these things disconnected? We found this "documentation" on what savedEnabled does, but we just want to make sure we aren't affecting anything else outside the ViewPagers own "state"

```
/**
 * This is the persistent state that is saved by ViewPager. Only needed if
 * you are creating a sublass of ViewPager that must save its own state, in
 * which case it should implement a subclass of this which contains that
 * state.
 */
```

Comment: The `TransactionTooLargeException` is thrown at half a megabyte of information. Even with 'hundreds' of fragments, that's the equivalent of saving many, many pages of information per fragment in your saved state, which is never what you should be using saved state for. Have you tried [looking at the state you've saved](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207158202#comment18) via [TooLargeTool](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool) and fixing the actual root cause of your issue?